# Mac OS X 10.6 SDK no longer works with Xcode 7.3?

Tags: xcode, macos

After updating from Xcode 7.2.1 to Xcode 7.3, building my project was getting the "run destination My Mac is not valid for Running the scheme".  I remembered that I needed to add the 10.6 SDK (which is, unfortunately, the base SDK of this project) into the Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs folder.  Then restart Xcode, and reselect the SDK in the project.

Except this time, the MacOSX10.6.sdk wasn't listed in any of the SDK popup menus in Build Settings.

Has Apple completely cut off Xcode's ability to use the 10.6 SDK?

Stephen

Answer (score 6):

> Has Apple completely cut off Xcode's ability to use the 10.6 SDK?

Yes, but you can work around it.

Open up `Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Info.plist`. There's a key in there, `MinimumSDKVersion`, which in 7.3 is set to `10.11`. Change it to `10.6` and it should work as before.

I have to ask, though: is there a reason you can't use a newer base SDK?

Comment: Yep -- deprecated Carbon interfaces.  Supposedly there is a way to add JUST the specific deprecated interfaces to the "Additional SDK" Build Setting, but I recall Apple's admonition that any additional SDKs need to be very limited and NOT "complete" SDKs -- but then they don't really explain how to create one of those...